# why does pgrep fail in this process monitor?

Tags: bash, monitor, grep

I have a monitor shell script that does effectively monitor and keep a process running.  But it often fails in the sense that it starts a second, third or more instance of the process.  I have also seen the pgrep command (pgrep -n -f wx_nanoserver) return the wrong pid at the command line...

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_process() {
  # echo "$ts: checking $1"
  [ "$1" = "" ]  && return 0
  [ `pgrep -n -f $1` ] && return 1 || return 0
}

while [ 1 ]; do 
  # timestamp
  ts=`date +%T`
  NOW=`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`

  # echo "$ts: begin checking..."
  check_process "wx_nanoserver"
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "$ts: not running, restarting..." && `php /var/www/wx_nanoserver.php > /var/www/logs/wx_output_$NOW.log 2> /var/www/logs/wx_error_$NOW.log &`
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Comment: how about not bothering with the check at all? Whenever your command exits it will start again. 
`while true; yourcommand ; done`
You can always put that loop into the background.

Comment: I have update the shell script per the excellent recommendations here.  But it has not solved the problem.  The php script still ends up with many instances running after a couple of days.  Any ideas on that?  At the command line you can't start more than one instance because it listens to a port and you get the error that there is already a listener at that port.  ...  It could be that all but one has crashed, but then still a mystery:  pgrep still sees a process and should not start another.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
pgrep -n -f "$1" && return 1 || return 0
```

if you use [ ], you will try to check pgrep stdout data, and your script did not compare it with empty space or sth, without [ ], will using pgrep exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Two weird things about your script:

```
  [ `pgrep -n -f $1` ] && return 1 || return 0
```

works through side effects. The ```` ``` part evaluates to either the pid of the process if found, or nothing if no process is found. The single ````[`notation is a synonym for the`test`builtin (or command on earlier systems) which happens to return`true`if its argument is a nonempty string and`false`if it is given no argument. So when a pid is found, the test becomes something like`[ 1234 ]`which evaluates to true and`[ ]` otherwise, which evaluates to false. That is indeed what you want, but it would be cleaner to write:

```
  pgrep -n -f "$1" &>/dev/null && return 1 || return 0
```

Another thing is

```
 `php /var/www/wx_nanoserver.php > /var/www/logs/wx_output_$NOW.log 2> /var/www/logs/wx_error_$NOW.log &`
```

where you use command substitution for no apparent reason. You're asking bash to evaluate the output of your command rather than simply running it. As its output is redirected, it always evaluates to an empty string so it has no further effect. A side effect is that the command is run in a subshell, which is a good thing to deamonize it. Though, it would be cleaner to write:

```
 ( php /var/www/wx_nanoserver.php > /var/www/logs/wx_output_$NOW.log 2> /var/www/logs/wx_error_$NOW.log & )
```

Not sure though what the actual problem might be. Seems to be working that way anyhow.

Final note, the back tick ``` `` notation has been deprecated in favour of the ```$()` notation.